Как правильно ппрописать условие на поиск массива?
Все привет. Есть проблема, не могу вывести корректно норматив по сотруднику.
Есть toggle ignoreSettlementDate === false и true когда включен.
Когда ignoreSettlementDate === true, то корректно приходит норматив в поле p(картинка не вставляется).
Данные приходят вот так


"employeeNormativeHistory": [
                {
                    "employeeNormObjectId": "7356608324074602497",
                    "updateTime": "2024-04-12",
                    "normative": 6.0
                },
                {
                    "employeeNormObjectId": "7355411339797725185",
                    "updateTime": "2024-03-26",
                    "normative": 10.0
                },
                {
                    "employeeNormObjectId": "7356880199799406593",
                    "updateTime": "2024-04-30",
                    "normative": 15.0
                },
                {
                    "employeeNormObjectId": "7356879607093919745",
                    "updateTime": "2024-04-26",
                    "normative": 5.0
                },
                {
                    "employeeNormObjectId": "7355411339797725186",
                    "updateTime": "2024-04-03",
                    "normative": 644.0
                },
                {
                    "employeeNormObjectId": "7355477980125331457",
                    "updateTime": "2024-04-09",
                    "normative": 65.0
                }
            ],



Так вот Если я ставлю ignoreSettlementDate === false, то приходит "-", хотя данные в этом поле есть и их много.
Мне нужно вывести только то что на сегодняшнее число(тоже самое что и при ignoreSettlementDate === true.


<p>{
                      selectedEmployee?.employeeNormativeHistory && selectedEmployee.employeeNormativeHistory.length > 0 ?
                        (ignoreSettlementDate === false ?
                          selectedEmployee?.employeeNormativeHistory
                            ?.filter((norm) => new Date(norm?.updateTime).toISOString().split('T')[0] === new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString().split('T')[0])
                            ?.map(norm => norm.normative)[0] || '-'
                          : selectedEmployee?.employeeNormativeHistory
                          ?.find((norm) => new Date(norm?.normative) <= new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)))?.normative || '-')
                        : '-'
                    }</p>



